# How to create AQGirdView with dynamic cell Size

Tags: iphone, ios, gridview, ios6, aqgridview

I used AQGridView for showing record in GridView. I want to customise all cell size. But AQGridView always take constant cell size and showing empty space if records view is small size.

Comment: If you are targeting iOS 6 and higher I would suggest you have a look at Apples [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @rckoenes my application support IOS 5 and higher.

Comment: You should check out [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) which is API compatible with `UICollectionView` and supports iOS 5

Comment: @Paul.s  This solution is working but items(Rows) are overlapped.